# Why the second “は“ in this sentence?

Tags: particle-は

Why is there a “は” after 以前 in the following sentence? I would have guessed it would read 以前 by itself or 以前に。

人々は人間しか言語を使えないと以前は考えていた。
People used to think that only humans could use language.

Found this sentence from the Examples in the dictionary app Midori.

Many thanks in advance!
Paul

Comment: This 「は」 has been discussed numerous times.  https://japanese.stackexchange.com/search?q=contrastive+%E3%81%AF

Comment: Read the threads and understand it (I think...). Many thanks for the speedy reply.